# Plotting 3D Tri-Surf Plots in plotly in R with a color legend

Tags: r, plotly, colorbar

I wish to create a 3D mesh and superimpose heatmap with each facet being assigned a uniform color according to an external variable (`f` in the code below). Here is my R code using plotly package:

```
library(plotly)
library(colorspace)
pal2 <- sequential_hcl(n = 99, h = c(320, 80), c = c(60, 65, 20), l = c(30, 95), 
                       power = c(0.7, 1.3), register = )
# Landmark data
lm <- matrix(c(0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1), ncol = 3)

# Triangulation file
it <- matrix(c(1,1,2,3,3,4), ncol = 3)

# Value associated with the 2 triangular facets
f <- c(2,5)
col <- pal2[findInterval(f,seq(from = 0, to = 7, length.out = length(pal2)))]

# Create 3D surface mesh
fig <- plot_ly(x=lm[,1], y=lm[,2], z=lm[,3], type="mesh3d",
               i=it[,1]-1, j=it[,2]-1, k=it[,3]-1,
               facecolor = col)

# Display plot
fig
```

Whereas this creates the figure seemingly correctly, there is no color legend created.
[image]

My color palette pal2 has 99 colors for the range of vaues from 0 to 7. I want a color legend that specifies this. But I am not sure how to do this in plotly in R.

Note that if I am to assign values to each **vertex (landmark)**, I am able to create heatmap and color legend using the following code:

```
lm <- matrix(c(0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1), ncol = 3)
it <- matrix(c(1,1,2,3,3,4), ncol = 3)
y <- c(1,2,3,4) # Value associated with the 4 landmarks

library(plotly)

thresholds_colors = seq(0, 1, length.out = 99)

library(colorspace)
pal2 <- sequential_hcl(n = 99, h = c(320, 80), c = c(60, 65, 20), l = c(30, 95), 
                       power = c(0.7, 1.3), register = )
palRGB <- col2rgb(pal2)
colors <- NULL
for (i in 1:99) {
 colors[i] <- paste0("rgb(", palRGB[1, i], ", ", palRGB[2, i], ", ", palRGB[3, i], ")")
}

# Create the surface mesh
mesh <- plot_ly(x = lm[,1], y = lm[,2], z = lm[,3], type = "mesh3d", 
                i = it[,1]-1, j = it[,2]-1, k = it[,3]-1,
                intensity = y,
                colorscale = list(thresholds_colors, colors),
                showscale = T, cmin = 0, cmax = 7)
mesh
```

[image]

I just cannot generate a color legend when values are assigned to **facets**. **All that I want is to add a color legend in the 1st figure, as is the case in the 2nd figure. Thank you!**

Some examples of 3D tri-surf plots in R plotly can be found [here](https://plotly.com/r/trisurf/). But none of the examples showed a color legend.

Comment: I am having the same problem right now. A possible workaround is to define two different traces for the two parts, color them with the intensity argument and then for each trace define a custom color ramp which is monochrome (set the min and max value to the exact same color).
But then of course you get two legend items and both of them show multiple numbers on the side as if they were a colorscale, which is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `color` argument for the breaks of your `colors` like this:

```r
library(plotly)
library(colorspace)
pal2 <- sequential_hcl(n = 99, h = c(320, 80), c = c(60, 65, 20), l = c(30, 95), 
                       power = c(0.7, 1.3), register = )
# Landmark data
lm <- matrix(c(0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1), ncol = 3)

# Triangulation file
it <- matrix(c(1,1,2,3,3,4), ncol = 3)

# Value associated with the 2 triangular facets
f <- c(2,5)
col <- pal2[findInterval(f,seq(from = 0, to = 7, length.out = length(pal2)))]

# Create 3D surface mesh
fig <- plot_ly(x=lm[,1], y=lm[,2], z=lm[,3], type="mesh3d",
               i=it[,1]-1, j=it[,2]-1, k=it[,3]-1,
               intensity = c(0, 0.5, 1),
               color = c(0, 0.5, 1),
               colors = col)

# Display plot
fig
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2023-04-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Please note that the two facets in my figure 1 are each homogenous in color (pure green or pure blue). However, in your output, the color in each facet is non-homogeneous, there is a color gradient in each facet. This is not what I expected. Do you have any idea about how to modify your code?